# XMLHttpRequest прием бинарных данных

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте, не могу обработать бинарные данные (**getXmlHttp**), как их можно преобразовать в Int. Задача стоит такая: есть сервер, который на запрос выдает данные графика в бинарном виде, мне надо их принять, обработать, преобразовать в тип integer, и вывести на график.Сильно не ругайтесь, я новичок в `JavaScript`! Ниже скриншот из отладчика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
    function ask_values() {
            req = getXmlHttp();
            req.open('POST', 'GetChart.cgi?', true);
            req.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
            req.send('0')
        }

        function updatePage() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {

                var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(req.response);
                /*console.log(req.response);*/
                add_voltage_data(uInt8Array);

            }
        }
```

Comment: По моему в любом случае передается просто строка, что потом с ней делать решать уже вам тут вроде норм статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/120917/

Comment: Что-то не выходит - получаю "undefined"(((...По-ссылке привожу скриншот из отладчика:https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2zad1f3ofjn51c/response.png?dl=0>

Comment: С кодировкой точно все в порядке?

Comment: С какой кодировкой?

Comment: пиши код иначе это на ТНТ в битву экстрасенсов нужно обращаться, я конечно могу назвать с пол сотню причин почему у тебя болит нога, но у меня такая же и не болит.

Comment: <code>
<pre>
    function ask_values() {
            req = getXmlHttp();
            req.open('POST', 'GetChart.cgi?', true);
            req.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
            req.send('0')
        }
        
        function updatePage() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {

                var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(req.response);
                /*console.log(req.response);*/
                add_voltage_data(uInt8Array);

            }
        }
</pre>
</code>

Comment: ну не в комменты  же=) Да и напиши условие задачи которую решаешь

Comment: есть сервер, который на запрос выдает данные графика в бинарном виде, мне надо их принять, обработать, преобразовать в тип integer, и вывести на график...как-то так.

Comment: блин, никто не знает?(((